# What would be the most efficient code of removing every key from a HashMap with the key value stored in an ArrayList?

Tags: java

Say I have an ArrayList with n elements and a HashMap with k elements, is there any faster way than just using a for loop and iterating through each key value of the HashMap?

Comment: You mean to say `ArrayList` contains key's value & you want to remove all keys from map whose values are in ArrayList?

Comment: If we assume that removing an entry from a `HashMap` can be done in time complexity `O(1)`, then removal of `n` entries cannot be faster than `O(n)`. Iterating over the `List` and removing each entry present from the list from the `HashMap` has time complexity `O(n)`. There is no faster approach.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, you should share your code, as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, take a look at [these guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254573/979052) for next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a

```
Map<K, V> yourMap = ...;
Collection<K> yourKeys = ...;
```

you can simply do

```
yourMap.keySet().removeAll(yourKeys);
```

Note that [`keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) won't be much faster than writing a loop and calling `remove` manually (because that's basically what it does internally), but it will be simpler to write and read.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, your `ArrayList` contains values & you want to remove keys which are mapped to values of `ArrayList` :

```
        Map<String, String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("A", "Val1");
        map.put("B", "Val2");
        map.put("C", "Val3");
        map.put("D", "Val4");
        List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        ll.add("Val1");
        ll.add("Val2");
        System.out.println(map);
        map.values().removeAll(list);
        System.out.println(map);
```